# Custom circular reference handler for serialization

Tags: php, symfony

Trying to serialize an entity which causes some circular reference issues

```
class Comment
{
    /**
     * @var Discussion
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Discussion", inversedBy="comments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $discussion;
}

class Discussion
{
    /**
     * @var Comment[]|ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Comment", mappedBy="discussion")
     */
    private $comments;
}
```

Since I'm using the `Serializer` component via injecting the `SerializerInterface` I tried to extend my `framework.yaml` with:

```
serializer:
    circular_reference_handler: App\Utils\CircularReferenceHandler
```

Where the handler class implements the `__invoke` method which simply returns the ID of the object:

```
public function __invoke($object, string $format = null, array $context = [])
{
    if (method_exists($object, 'getId')) {
        return $object->getId();
    }
    return '';
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work and I'm resulting in an endless loop (exceeding available memory). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why does a comment need to know what discussions it belongs to?  Why not just remove that @ManyToOne from "Comment"?

Comment: Bidirectional entity validity (and all the benefits from it). In addition removing this relation would not solve the problem, since the same relations apply for comments/users, votes/comments, etc..

Comment: 1) Writing a custom "CircularReferenceHandler" was a wrong turn: I'm glad you recognized that.  2) Just as a class generally shouldn't need to know what "type" it is (if you need "typeof", or "dynamic_cast", or whatever - you likely have a design flaw), a "comment" needn't know it's parent "discussion", nor it's associated user, etc.  ANYWAY: Q: What ORM are you using?  Doctrine?  If so, a good solution might be to use a [NativeQuery](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/native-sql.html)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to use the serializer and you're running into issues with the ManyToOne relationship causing a circular reference error.

I solved this in the past with:

```
$normalizer->setignoredattributes()
```

This allows you to ignore ignore attributes of an object your trying to serialize. So this way you will only serialize the discussions reference down to comments, but not the comments objects reference back to discussion. You'll ignore the comments objects reference back to discussion.

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;

$normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer();
$normalizer->setIgnoredAttributes(array('age'));
$encoder = new JsonEncoder();

$serializer = new Serializer(array($normalizer), array($encoder));
$serializer->serialize($person, 'json');
```

The key here being:

```
$normalizer->setIgnoredAttributes(array('age'));
```

That was simply the example from the documentation which you may read here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#ignoring-attributes

Comment: I think I understood what you were asking, but if I misunderstood, let me know! Hope it helps.